# Custom ScrollPane using just a Panel or any other Container

Tags: java, scroll, awt

I'm trying to mimic a `ScrollPane` by simply inheriting from a `Panel` which itself moves its child around.
Should be a simple task but the child doesn't get clipped properly, meaning if I scroll around using `setScrollPosition(Point)` the content is visible although its outside the parent `Panel`.

```
public class ScrollFrame
    extends Container
{
    public ScrollFrame() {
        setLayout(null);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
        super.paint(g);
    }

    public void setScrollPosition(Point p) {
        setScrollPosition(p.x, p.y);
    }

    public void setScrollPosition(int x, int y) {
        synchronized (getTreeLock()) {
            Component component = getComponent(0);

            int viewPortWidth = getWidth(),
                viewPortHeight = getHeight(),
                componentWidth = component.getWidth(),
                componentHeight = component.getHeight(),
                componentX = component.getX(),
                componentY = component.getY();

            if (x < 0) {
                x = 0;
            } else if (x > 0 && x + viewPortWidth > componentWidth) {
                x = componentWidth - viewPortWidth;
                if (x < 0)
                    x = 0;
            }

            if (y < 0) {
                y = 0;
            } else if (y > 0 && y + viewPortHeight > componentHeight) {
                y = componentHeight - viewPortHeight;
                if (y < 0)
                    y = 0;
            }

            component.setLocation(x * -1, y * -1);
            validate();
        }
    }

    public Point getScrollPosition() {
        synchronized (getTreeLock()) {
            Point p =  getComponent(0).getLocation();
            p.x *= -1;
            p.y *= -1;
            return p;
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem:** The child component added to the `ScrollFrame` is visible outside the boundaries of the `ScrollFrame`.

And finally a SSCCE for some C&P testing, just click into the red area and move the mouse up and down:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class TestScrollPane extends Frame implements MouseListener,
    MouseMotionListener
{
    /* starting point */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TestScrollPane window = new TestScrollPane();
        window.setSize(800, 480);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    /*
     * a translucent element to be placed above all other components to receive
     * the MouseEvents
     */
    public class GlassPane extends Component
    {
        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            super.paint(g);
        }
    }

    public class ScrollContainer extends Container
    {
        public ScrollContainer()
        {
            setLayout(null);
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth() - 1, getHeight() - 1);
            super.paint(g);
        }

        public void printComponents(Graphics g)
        {
            Component c = getComponent(0);
            Point p = c.getLocation();

            Graphics cg = g.create();

            try {
                cg.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                cg.translate(p.x * -1, p.y * -1);
                c.paintAll(cg);
            } finally {
                cg.dispose();
            }
        }

        public void setScrollPosition(Point p)
        {
            setScrollPosition(p.x, p.y);
        }

        public void setScrollPosition(int x, int y)
        {
            synchronized (getTreeLock()) {
                Component component = getComponent(0);

                int viewPortWidth = getWidth(), viewPortHeight = getHeight(), componentWidth = component
                    .getWidth(), componentHeight = component.getHeight(), componentX = component
                    .getX(), componentY = component.getY();

                if (x < 0) {
                    x = 0;
                } else if (x > 0 && x + viewPortWidth > componentWidth) {
                    x = componentWidth - viewPortWidth;
                    if (x < 0)
                        x = 0;
                }

                if (y < 0) {
                    y = 0;
                } else if (y > 0 && y + viewPortHeight > componentHeight) {
                    y = componentHeight - viewPortHeight;
                    if (y < 0)
                        y = 0;
                }

                component.setLocation(x * -1, y * -1);
            }
        }

        public Point getScrollPosition()
        {
            synchronized (getTreeLock()) {
                Point p = getComponent(0).getLocation();
                p.x *= -1;
                p.y *= -1;
                return p;
            }
        }
    }

    private ScrollContainer scrollPane;
    private Panel scrollPaneContainer;
    private GlassPane glassPane;
    private boolean scrolling = false;
    private Point scrollingStartMouse;
    private Point scrollingStartPane;

    public TestScrollPane()
    {
        /* simple test window */
        super("TestScrollPane");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                e.getWindow().dispose();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        setLayout(null);

        /*
         * the ScrollPane provides the ability to show only a limited of a much
         * larger child element. Note that the ScrollPane is a container for
         * only ONE element, but the child element may act as a container, e.g.
         * a Panel
         */
        scrollPane = new ScrollContainer();
        scrollPane.addMouseListener(this);
        scrollPane.setBounds(30, 50, 300, 300);

        /*
         * the element we place in the scrollpane, a panel with null layout to
         * place the children
         */
        scrollPaneContainer = new Panel();
        scrollPaneContainer.setLayout(null);

        /* add some random buttons for testing purposes */
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
            Button button = new Button("Click Me " + i);
            button.addMouseListener(this);
            button.setBounds(0, 40 * i, 100, 30);
            scrollPaneContainer.add(button);
        }

        /*
         * a translucent component on top of all elements placed inside the
         * scrollPaneContainer to receive the MouseEvent's and properly scroll
         * the ScrollPane or propagate the event
         */
        glassPane = new GlassPane();
        glassPane.setBounds(0, 0, 1, 1);
        glassPane.addMouseListener(this);
        glassPane.addMouseMotionListener(this);

        /*
         * we do need to add the GlassPane first to place it above all other
         * elements
         */
        // scrollPaneContainer.add(glassPane);

        /*
         * the GlassPane and the scrollPaneContainer need to have the same size.
         * you have to set a size on the scrollPaneContainer else there won't be
         * any scrolling ;)
         */
        scrollPaneContainer.setSize(100, 1190);
        scrollPaneContainer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 1190));

        /* place the scrollPaneContainer (Panel) inside the ScrollPane */
        scrollPane.add(scrollPaneContainer);

        scrollPane.setBounds(30, 30, 150, 300);
        glassPane.setBounds(30, 30, 30, 300);

        Panel all = new Panel();
        all.setLayout(null);
        all.setBounds(30, 30, 400, 400);
        all.add(glassPane);
        all.add(scrollPane);

        add(all);
    }

    /* MouseListener implementation */
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource().equals(glassPane)) {
            scrolling = false;
        }
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource().equals(glassPane)) {
            scrolling = true;
            scrollingStartMouse = e.getPoint();
            scrollingStartPane = scrollPane.getScrollPosition();
        }
    }

    /* MouseMotionListener implementation */
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (scrolling) {
            Point currentPos = e.getPoint();

            int mouseDeltaX = currentPos.x - scrollingStartMouse.x;
            int mouseDeltaY = currentPos.y - scrollingStartMouse.y;

            scrollPane.setScrollPosition(scrollingStartPane.x - mouseDeltaX,
                scrollingStartPane.y - mouseDeltaY);
        }
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
    {
    }

    void log(String message)
    {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    void log(String message, MouseEvent e)
    {
        log(e.getComponent().getClass().getName() + ": " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: please my questions ??? , what do you really needed or want ot display or ..., somewhere I lost, EDIT ---> and why AWT Components not Swing JComponents, there could be difference in fact that rellated answerers for AWT Compoents wholesale died in last century

Comment: Cause I'm unable to use Swing, and please don't add a Swing tag since it's not a Swing related question. For your problem see the edit.

Comment: everything 1) depends of code in your main method, 2) ScrollPane hate NullLayout by default don't do that, 3) another issues hidded somewhere, 4) in the case that you'll be convert that to the Swing, then you have chance get real answer, then conversion back to AWT is up to you  4) better would be post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), 5) +1 for posting an images

Comment: First of all thanks for your effort. Since the Swing toolkit isn't directly comparable to AWT it's not certain that a working Swing solutions is translatable to AWT. And just as a little advice, you should spend some more thinking on your spelling and grammar. I'll post a SSCCE shortly.

Comment: hmmm now again my question what do you really to want, because there are these choices 1) put Buttons to the awt.List, then to awt.Scrollpane, 2) let's these Buttons in the Panel and add Panel to awt.Scrollpane, for why heels on this world you implemented GlassPane (I take that as joke)